# Layout features and angular-material2

Tags: web, material-components

In the mdl, i saw implemented layout features (grid, footer, etc). But i haven't seen implemented in material-components-web yet. Will be a future feature, or is there other way to do it?

Another question,

Also I have seen angular-material2 that it doesn't use material-components-web. In the future, (since angular and  material-components members are of the google team), May be that angular-material2 works with material-components-web?.

Comment: We recently created an issue for grid-based layouts for Material Components for the web :) https://github.com/material-components/material-components-web/issues/170 As for angular-material2 interop, we are working closely with the angular team to figure out the best way in which our teams can work together.

Comment: not sure about material, but there is another excellent library which is built-on top of angular-material2 (a extension of this). https://github.com/Teradata/covalent